# Comparing columns containing NULLS

Tags: sql-server

Suppose I have this table:

```
CREATE TABLE t (id int, cola int, colb int);
INSERT INTO t VALUES (1, 1, 1), (2, 1, 2), (3, 1, NULL), (4, NULL, 4);

    id  cola    colb
1   1   1       1
2   2   1       2
3   3   1       NULL
4   4   NULL    4
```

I want to find the rows where cola does not equal colb. I would expect rows 2-4 to be returned when I write:

```
SELECT * FROM t WHERE cola != colb
```

But instead only the second row is returned. In order to pull rows 2-4 I have to write:

```
SELECT * FROM t
WHERE cola != colb
OR (cola IS NULL AND colb IS NOT NULL)
OR (cola IS NOT NULL AND colb IS NULL)
```

Is there a cleaner way to do this?

Tested here: http://rextester.com/VJYFX19301

Answer (score 3, accepted):

probably the easiest way would be to use an isnull() wrapper, say:

```
SELECT * FROM t WHERE isnull(cola, -1) != isnull(colb, -1)
```

assuming this is a fairly small table.  there are some potential performance caveats to joining on a function, as this is doing, but maybe in your case it's ok?